# How can I script 'Overwrite Table'

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool

Here is documentation on it, but it doesn't have Python code associated. I want to script this so I can make it run automatically after another model runs as a precondition.

My current workflow is: in ArcCatalog run the precondition model (mentioned above, it just updates a datatable) > Open ArcGIS Pro > right click the table I want to republish with the updated info > Sharing > Overwrite Table.

[image: location of tool process mentioned above I want to script]

Ideally I could just include the last couple steps as part of the script when I run the tool in the first step.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/sharing/overview/overwrite-standalone-table.htm

Comment: At the feature class level,  overwrite is an environment property https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/env.htm

Comment: Yes I know about that property, but I think what I'm asking about is different. I want to overwrite a published table in portal.